# exe fail to start in Windows scheduled task

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

sorry another schedule task question. I hope we can resolve this one too.

I have a schedule task on Windows 2008.
This works ok, but ~4 weeks the following happens.
The task is starting and execute like it should. Log entries are ok.
But in the script is a WINSCP.exe script, which is just ignored. 
When you do the basic tests like run in CMD, check account and permissions all is ok. But when you schedule the task (or "run" from scheduler task) the WINSCP.exe is not even starting in the script. The Script contain a list of commands like copy, md, move - all executed ok, only the WINSCP.EXE is not.
While the script is running, no Process seen in the task manager.

After a reboot of the server all back to normal.
I see nothing in the eventvwr. I can't find any hanging task in task manager. Accounts are all ok. This happens on 2 different servers.

Would be great if you may have some proposals to chekc out for me.

regards,
HEP

Comment: You say that rebooting resolves the issue. What happens if you restart just the Task Scheduler service instead?

Comment: Good point - next time it happens I give it a try. But given that the scheduling itself works absolute fine I doubt that's the solution ... I keep you posted.

Comment: I don't know if it'll help, but it might help point toward the cause. When you do get a chance to test it, if you haven't been able to fix the problem before, make sure to [edit] your question to include the results of that attempt. Comments are subject to deletion at any time for almost any reason, and should be considered ephemeral.

Comment: "While the script is running, no Process seen in the task manager." - Check "Show processes of all users" and the CMD process. Add the Command Line" column to the process view.